# Strange issue in PHP for loop

Tags: php

I have this simple loop:

```
for ($user = 1; $user <= 219; $user++)
{    
    echo "Yo <br />";
    $pos = 1;
    echo "Set pos to $pos <br />";
    do
    {
        echo "Doing user $user , $pos <br />";
        $pos++;
    }
    while ($pos <= 8);

    echo "Done user $user ,  $pos <br /><br ";
}
```

When I run this, only for the first iteration does it echo the first 'yo'. For every iteration from 2 to 219, the output starts from `Set pos to $pos`. Sample:

```
Yo 
Set pos to 1 
Done user 1 , 9 

Set pos to 1 
Done user 2 , 9 

Set pos to 1 
Done user 3 , 9 

Set pos to 1 
Done user 4 , 9 

Set pos to 1 
Done user 5 , 9
```

What happened to this statement:

```
    echo "Yo <br />";
```

Why is it executed only for the first iteration and not for any others?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is executed in every iteration, you forgot to close `<br />` at the end.

```
echo "Done user $user ,  $pos <br /><br />";
```

So, if you check the source of the page, it should say:

```
<br Yo <br />
```

Comment: kill me now. kill me now kill me now. kill me now kill me now. kill me now kill me now. kill me now kill me now. kill me now kill me now. kill me now kill me now. kill me now kill me now. kill me now kill me now. kill me now kill me now. kill me now kill me now. kill me now kill me now

Comment: That's actually a solid reaction.

Comment: LOL, he must be very annoyed to miss an HTML typo inside an echo statement, sometimes i spend hours to find that, i know how you feel @ClickUpvote

Answer (score 0):

If your `echo "Yo <br />"` was inside the `do{}` loop, then it would execute with every iteration, just before `"Doing user [etc.]"`. Right now it's not inside the `do{}` loop, it's just inside the `for()` loop.

So, you'll only see the "Yo" after `$pos` exceeds 8 and the `for` loop begins another iteration.

Comment: But he doesn't see it every iteration of the `for` loop, that's the problem. See Frank's answer.

Comment: Ah, yeah... I missed the lack of closure on that last `<br />`.